# java - convert complex java object to json

Tags: java, json

I have a class like below-

```
public class Person {   
    private String firstName;
    private String lastname;
    private Address address;

   // getters and setters
}

public class Address {
    private String streetName;
    private String postCode;
    private Contact contact;
   // getters and setters
}

public class Contact {
    private String telephone;
    private String email;
   // getters and setters
}
```

i am converting it to the json object using gson library like this-

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .serializeNulls()
                    .setPrettyPrinting()
                    .create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(new Person()));
```

then i get json like-

```
{
  "firstName": null,
  "lastname": null,
  "address": null
}
```

but i am looking for a json like-

```
{
  "firstName": null,
  "lastname": null,
  "address": {
      "streetName": null,
      "postCode": null,
      "contact": {
         "telephone": null,
         "email": null
       }
   }
}
```

can anybody please help me in achieving this?

Comment: You need to actually create a `Address` instance filled with `null` s - it makes no sense for the JSON converter to convert the field `address` with value `null` to anything other than `null`. `null` is something very different than `new Address(null, null)`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the resulting JSON you obtain is the expected one: `new Person().address` field is null (if you don't initialize it in `Person`'s constructor), so it is serialized to `null`.

The output you are searching for corresponds to the serialization of something like

```
Person p = new Person();
Address a = new Address();
a.setContact(new Contact());
p.setAddress(a);
gson.toJson(p);
```

which is a `Person`'s instance different from `new Person()`...

Comment: is there a way to auto initialize member variables of a class?

Comment: @Vibs See my answer for that

Comment: You can set default value for class fields adding an assignment at definition place, as in the response by @George Derpi, or you can set theirs value through constructor's parameters os setters: imho constructor injection is preferable, but if your class is a DTO setter injection makes sense, too. Inline fields initialization is ok for collaborators that implement some related piece of functionality but imho not for data members... but the final, right choice it's up to you: it depends on the context you're using this classes in.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your Person class to

```
public class Person {   
    private String firstName;
    private String lastname;
    private Address address;

    public Person() {
        this(new Address());
    }

    public Person(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Otherwise there is no Address, hence the **null** in your JSON

Comment: I think it's better to inject an empty address object via a constructor or setter

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I absolutely agree. But I wanted to very clearly show where the problem was situated, within the example code the asker provided. I have edited the example to be best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You should add address as object to your person class not null.

Modify your code
-Add constructor to Person take address object as parameter

```
  public class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastname;
        private Address address;

        public Person(Address address) {
            this.address=address;
        }

        // getters and setters
    }
```

then replace the print line with this one:

```
System.out.println(gson.toJson(new Person(new Address())));
```